# Typing pipe-like semantics using a single object parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm looking to preserve inferred generic types when piping the results from functions that are passed via a single object parameter (example below).

I know that a lot of issues with `pipe`-like semantics have been solved by https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215 but I'm wondering - because I'm constrained to pass arguments as props to a React component - whether a similar effect can be achieved with object parameters as well as just positional parameters.

As an example of what I mean, consider:

```js
// Example input

declare const f: (path: string) => { data: { id: string } }

// Piping works with positional args (as fixed by: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215)

declare function pipePos<A, B, C>(
  f: (a: A) => B,
  g: (b: B) => C,
  h: (c: C) => void
): void;

pipePos(f, b => b.data, c => c.id) // `c` is inferred as `{ id: string }` 

// Piping does not work with object args (seemingly no precedence based on generic ordering)
// This is the case I care about for React props reasons

declare function pipeObj<A, B, C>(props: {
  f: (a: A) => B;
  g: (b: B) => C;
  h: (c: C) => void
}): void;

pipeObj({ f, g: b => b.data, h: c => c.id }) // `c` is inferred as `unknown` 

// Piping works for a more limited case with object args when the value of `C` is instead returned to be used outside the function

declare function pipeObj<A, B, C>(props: {
  f: (a: A) => B;
  g: (b: B) => C;
}): C;

const c: { id: string } = pipeObj({ f, g: b => b.data }); // `c` is inferred as `{ id: string }`
```

Given the recency with which the positional case was solved I'm assuming that this may not be possible but perhaps I'm missing some possible workaround.